# How to find a complete set of orthonormal basis when given a set of equations?

Tags: orthonormal

I was given this set of 3 formulas and asked to find a complete set of orthonormal basis for it:

$$s1(t) = u(t) − u(t − 1)$$

$$s2(t) = u(t − 2) − u(t − 3)$$

$$s3(t) = u(t) − u(t − 3)$$

I'm not sure how to find the complete set of orthonormal basis for these graphs, honestly I am not even certain of the meaning of "complete orthonormal basis". The problem comes from an engineering class but I believe it is more mathematical than anything else so I'm asking here. I don't need a solution but I would like to know how to go about solving this kind of problem on my own (the logic behind it and the process).

as asked for in the comments, I am not sure about the inner product space but u(t) is the unit step function as seen here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/signals_and_systems/signals_basic_types.htm basically a signal with y = 1 and varying length across x

Comment: More context is needed: what is the inner product space we work with, and what is $u$?

Comment: The question mentions being complex but I'm not sure whether that answers the inner product space question, but I have updated with u

Comment: The function u seems to be the Heaviside step function and t is probably time. An orthonormal basis is defined in texts. An orthonormal basis would enable the three functions to be defined as linear combinations of functions in the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here, but it appears that: S1 = 1 from 0 to 1; S2 = 1 from 2 to 3; and S3 = 1 from 0 to 3. 
So S3 overlaps S1 and S2. So you can subtract S1 and S2 from S3 to create a new coordinate S*
S* = S3-S2-S1 = 1 from 1 to 2 
Thus S1, S2 and S* have nothing in common, hence orthonormal. Again, guessing.

Comment: So basically a simpler way to understand orthonormal is that the set has no regions overlapping one another?

Comment: I suspect so. If you multiply $S_1$ times $S_2$ (or $S_1$ times $S_3$, or $S_2$ times $S_3$) then you get zero. That seems analogous to the dot product of **i**, **j**, **k** in Cartesian coordinates.